# Strange API issue when looping in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, api, curl

I'm working with this API here: https://gatewaydtx1.giact.com/gVerifyV2/POST/Verify.asmx?op=Call using curl in php.  I am able to do a test just fine on a single call to the API.  However when I try to loop over several records, I get an error on every attempt after the first one.

Here's my code:

```
<?
//set the variables for posting
$CompanyID = "123";
$Token = "013443234-224e-4f46-bad4-6693deae2231";
$CheckNumber = "1";
$Amount = "30";
$UniqueID = "111";
$url = "https://gatewaydtx1.giact.com/gVerifyV2/POST/Verify.asmx/Call";

//Get the records from table
$sql = "SELECT id,account_no,routing_no FROM banktable WHERE(status = 'queued') LIMIT 0,100";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error: " . mysql_error() . "<br>");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $RoutingNumber = $row['routing_no'];
    $AccountNumber = $row['account_no'];    
    //Do the curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;)");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    $post_array = array(
        "CompanyID"=>$CompanyID,
        "Token"=>$Token,
        "RoutingNumber"=>$RoutingNumber,
        "AccountNumber"=>$AccountNumber,
        "CheckNumber"=>$CheckNumber,
        "Amount"=>$Amount,
        "UniqueID"=>$UniqueID,
    );

    //url-ify the data
    foreach($post_array as $key=>$value){
        $post_array_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
    }
    $post_array_string = rtrim($post_array_string,'&');

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($post_array ));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post_array_string);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $response;
    curl_close($ch);
}
?>
```

And here's what this code outputs after looping 4 rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.giact.com/webservices/gVerifyV2/">33302261|true|No Data|ND00</string>
Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).
```

Note that the first record it tried produced a correct result.  After that, the errors. And even though I mention my loop specifically here, I should note that this also happens if I simply hard code two or more curls on the page.

Comment: `//url-ify the data`  => luckily we have `http_build_query` :P FOr the rest it looks more like a data problem to me: if you shuffle your input around (i.e., skip that first record, go straight for the second): does it then suddenly succeed, or does it fail just the same as it did being called second?

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions if they solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
//url-ify the data
foreach($post_array as $key=>$value){
    $post_array_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
$post_array_string = rtrim($post_array_string,'&');
```

I think you need to clear the $post_array_string variable in each loop.

```
unset($post_array_string);
```

Comment: PHP does not scope as tightly as C++ and many other languages. Variables declared inside loops are accessible outside of them.

Answer (score 0):

Before:

`foreach($post_array as $key=>$value){`

Add:

`$post_array_string = '';`

Or you can use `http_build_query()` function.